# How to animate a textblock so it appears as though it is bouncing on a surface in XAML or C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**Hello, if this question is not clear or needs any improving/additional information please tell me in the comments.**

I'm creating an app and in the game the user of the app gets xp by playing and winning challenges. I am interested in creating a bouncing text animation, here is what I'm wanting:

[image]

I heard you can simulate this using BounceEase but I have not found enough information/resources in order to achieve this certain effect.

I hope the information I have given is satisifatory enough in order for you to try to find a solution to this, if not, please tell me.

Comment: `y = |sin x|`? Or do you need a real physics?

Comment: aepot I'm not entirely sure what you are meaning but if I am not clear enough I am looking for a solution to this in C# or XAML, preferably in C# using DoubleAnimation.

Comment: As an idea. You can play with [`Easing Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/easing-functions). If you apply different easing functions to X and Y, you may get a desired curve.

Comment: OK I will have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `BounceEasy` function to animate the `y` translation. Check the following demo.

```
void BounceText(string text, int x, int y)
{
    var tb = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = text,
        RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(x, y)
    };
    RootCanvas.Children.Add(tb);

    //--x animation 1
    var xAnim = new DoubleAnimation(x, x + 40, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.6)));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim, tb);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));
    
    //--x animation 2
    var xAnim2 = new DoubleAnimation(x + 40, x + 80, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.6)))
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6)
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnim2, tb);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnim2, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.X"));
    
    //--y animation 
    var yAnim = new DoubleAnimation(y, y - 40, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.3)))
    {
        AutoReverse = true,
        EasingFunction = new BounceEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseIn, Bounces = 0 },
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2)
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnim, tb);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnim, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Y"));

    var sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Children.Add(xAnim);
    sb.Children.Add(yAnim);
    sb.Children.Add(xAnim2); //--add this to animate 2 times

    sb.Begin();
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
BounceText("+2 XP", 80, 80);
```

You can show the items using a canvas, for example:

```
...
<Canvas x:Name="RootCanvas"/>
...
```

Comment: Works well, thanks for the descriptive and well-though-out answer.